# Kendo spring demo project missing database

Tags: spring, kendo-ui, kendo-treeview

I'm trying to run Kendo spring demo application, most of the demos works but whenever I run remote binding examples I'm getting

> [SQLITE_ERROR] SQL error or missing database (no such table:
>   Employees)]

It seems like it couldn't find the database, where can I find the database or how can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The database should be available under the following folder:

***spring-demos\src\main\webapp\WEB-INF\sample.db***

Comment: I fund the database and checked the servlet.xml and it is pointing to the right path but I'm still getting the error.